# what is the ideal order of fields to have in a contact form?

Tags: ordering, order, input-fields

I'm working on a contact form and was wondering on the order of fields.
if I should start with the subject first and then name, email and message field or name, email subject and message field.

Comment: Searching Google for *"name email subject message" "contact us"* reveals about 19 times as many references than does *"subject name email message" "contact us"*. On the one hand [Apple uses NESM](http://www.apple.com/uk/contact/feedback.html) - easy. On the other hand Microsoft wants you to choose a product, select an known problem, indicate business or personal, enter product code or accept that charges may apply, provide details, supply personal information before deciding whether to let you submit a message. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

Imagine that the form is an actual conversation with a person. The first thing you want to do is find out who the person is and then determine what you want to talk about.

Name
Email
Subject
Message

Comment: This is also a great way to start thinking about the dialog in terms of gradual engagement. Start with the simple stuff so they'll be more committed to completing the more complicated stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for arriving here 2 years later, but I don't agree with the answer given earlier.

Like Atanasio says, imagine that the form is an actual conversation with a person. However: if you're having a conversation, try not to focus on what *you* want, but try to think about what the other person needs. His primary goal is to send you a message; telling you his name and email address is just a side issue. See also [this answer to "Order of fields in contact forms"](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/28532/1905).